# Centering an image with display:table-cell

Tags: css

I want to center-align and bottom-align an `<img>` in a container block. The `<img>` needs to be constrained to the container dimensions, so `max-width:100%` and `max-height:100%` are set on it. Also I need to align a label to the top-right corner of the `<img>`, which makes things more complicated.

I have a working version using `display:inline-block` and `line-height` (below):

```css
.block {
  line-height: 236px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 236px;
  height: 236px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
.flex {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 18px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 236px;
  max-height: 236px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/x7q4E80.png" />
    <label>X</label>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- 374 × 187 -->
<div class="block">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dBy1WKI.png" />
    <label>X</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/benwise/pen/PNNEjr?editors=1100)

However this requires a reset on the `line-height` of the label. Is it possible to use a different method like `display:table-cell` to center and bottom-align the content?

My closest attempt is below:

```css
.block {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 236px;
  height: 236px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
.flex {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 236px;
  max-height: 236px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/x7q4E80.png" />
    <label>X</label>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- 374 × 187 -->
<div class="block">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dBy1WKI.png" />
    <label>X</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/benwise/pen/EKKoKX?editors=1100)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code same as like below.

```css
.block1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.block2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.block1 a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.block1 a label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.block2 a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.block2 a label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <div class="ctr-algn">
    <a href="#">
      <img src=".../images">
      <label>x</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="ctr-algn">
    <a href="#">
      <img src=".../images">
      <label>x</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you solve your issue.